# Android Debounce / TakeLast RxJava Never Receives Last Item After OnCompleted()

Tags: android, rx-java, onactivityresult, debouncing

**Background**

My code below aims to prevent an image being uploaded everytime a user selects an image. Essentially my aim was to create 'cool off' period before starting the upload to save the User's battery and data.

**Issue**

The code works well, except when the Fragment is destroyed OnComplete unsubscribes the subscriber before the last item is emitted therefore the latest selected image is never uploaded. I imagine this is the correct behaviour but I am at a loss how to solve it.

I also had very little luck with `debounce` and had to use `TakeLast` instead. The result is what I wanted however.

Maybe an AsyncSubject would be better but I am unsure of the way forward. Thanks.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int DO_STUFF_REQUEST_CODE = 123173;
    private static final int DEBOUNCE_TIME = 20;

    private PublishSubject<Object> startPhotoUploadPublishSubject;

    @Bind(R.id.photo)
    ImageView photo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startPhotoUploadPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();


        startPhotoUploadPublishSubject
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .takeLast(DEBOUNCE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new StartUploadPhotoIntentServiceSubscriber());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        startPhotoUploadPublishSubject.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {

                startPhotoUploadPublishSubject.onNext(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.photo)
    public void choosePhotoSelected() {

        Intent chooserIntent = ...etc
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, DO_STUFF_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private class StartUploadPhotoIntentServiceSubscriber extends Subscriber<Object> {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            //do nothing
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ON COMPLETE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            //we shouldnt have any errors
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object object) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ON NEXT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent uploadPhotoIntent = new Intent(
                getActivity(), UploaderIntentService.class);
            getActivity().startService(uploadPhotoIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An AsyncSubject instead of the PublishSubject sounds better but I don't know the Android lifecycle well enough; since you call onCompleted() in the onDestroy, I'd think getActivity() doesn't work any longer.

Comment: Just to get that right: Do you want to upload multiple items - given enough time has passed in between - or just one? This `takeLast()` makes me assume you want to upload only one item, but your text makes me assume you want to upload multiple items.

Comment: My original plan was to upload multiple items as the user may change their mind but not leave the activity, therefore allowing multiple items would be more practical. I hoped to use debounce rather than take last but it wouldn't trigger onNext

Comment: Use a service which runs until everything is uploaded. You need to decouple it from the UI lifecycle. There is nothing else you can do.

Comment: I guess I could add items to my intent service and check if something with the same signature already exists or if items for the same request are pending then cancel them. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

I assume what's happening is that the Fragment is destroyed before those 20 seconds of bouncing, right?

When calling onCompleted, the onComplete method in the subscriber is going to be called as well, therefore onNext is not going to be executed because the subscriber hasn't called it.

What about this?

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    startPhotoUploadPublishSubject.onNext();
    startPhotoUploadPublishSubject.onCompleted();
}
```

It might work in your situation. I think for this scenario, there's no difference between an AsyncSubject or a PublishSubject.

Hope it helps